# Using ember's link-to helper to link to different pages based on a computed property

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I would like a certain link on my handlebars page to dynamically change based on a computed property that I have in the page's javascript file.

I discovered a feature of handlebars called Subexpressions but it doesn't seem to allow you to insert a computed property into the middle of a handlebars link-to expression, which would be a simple way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do. The more I look it seems like this may not be possible with vanilla ember.js handlebars helpers, but I figured I should ask here first.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just link (`transitionTo`) from within an action?

Comment: do you mean this - check this https://ember-twiddle.com/dd13cb592f28dc3458243d9be2b20998

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can directly include computed property in link-to helper.

```
{{#link-to anyComputedProperty }} Reports {{/link-to}}
```

Even you can include subexpressions for generating routes for link-to helper.

```
{{#link-to (concat 'new' anyComputedProperty) }} Reports {{/link-to}}.
```

As torazaburo mentioned in comments, you can invoke actions to route/controller and from there you can use transitionTo/transitionToRoute method respectively.